# Which login mothed to use with this specific website

Tags: php, authentication

I need to login via php to our university system on following address

https://isit.uhk.cz/isit/

But the login system is very specific from other websites (it's from 1994) and other methods used to login websites doesn't work. I even tried to export cookies from browser and request that page with them, but it doesnť work either.

Is there any other way how to pass this specific login method?

Comment: That's HTTP basic auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is HTTP Basic Authorization.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

1. Server check sepcific Authorization header in request, if header exist and included encoded username/password - server allow access to resource. If not, go to point 2
2. Server send specific 401 status code to browser
3. Browser show standard login form
4. Browser add encoded username/password to header and repeat request. (@see point 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$credentials = "username:password"; 'change username passwod with the yours
 $ch = curl_init('https://isit.uhk.cz/isit/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0',
  "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials)));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo htmlentities($response);
```

but it is not good way to use this under your localhost